# Rigid Connection of Bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

[image: Crank Linkage]

This crank linkage works, except I need to constrain the larger bone to the bone labeled "crank" so they behave as a solid link. When I add rigging to the tail of the larger bone, the larger bone is able to pivot at the juncture of the three bones. Parenting (Ctrl-P) doesn't seem to help...

Comment: I am unsure as to your goals and problem.  What are you ultimately trying to do, and what is happening instead?

Comment: I'm modeling a kinetic sculpture of a man pushing on a wall. The mechanism is shown in this short video: https://youtu.be/VCeFdhtJj6g

Comment: The upper end of the large bone will connect to other linkages, but it needs to stay rigid with the bone I labeled "crank". Link-1 needs to attach in the body of the link object I will model, instead of an end of the link. When I model the link object, it could be a child of either the bone labeled "crank" or the large bone, since they will have the same movement.

Comment: Could you upload your blend files here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so I can try to help you?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution and it's really simple. Since the big bone has the same movement as the bone labeled "crank", I really don't need it. I made a link object the length of both "crank" and the big bone and made that a child of "crank". Then I made the origin of the link object at the top of where the big bone was and I built the second armature (not shown) off that point. Then I made the connecting bone copy the location of the link object.